# how do I concat page variables in jekyll loops

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm accessing a page variable in a jekyll loop like below:

```ruby

```
{% assign kind = page.categories | first %}
{% for post in site.categories.[kind] | limit: 5 %}
    {% unless post.url == page.url %}
       <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}" class = 'post-url'>
       <img src = '{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/{{ post.image }}.jpg>
          <h2 itemprop="name headline">{{ page.title | escape }}</h2>
          <time >{{ post.date | date: date_format }}</time>
       </a>
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

```

Although the page builds successfully it outputs an error saying **Expected page id but found open_square in "post in site.categories.[kind] | limit: 5"**

How can I avoid this add still be able to use the ***page.categories | first*** variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use `site.categories[kind]` instead of `site.categories.[kind]`

There shouldn't be any dot after "categories"

Comment: Thanks. That did not work though; I still get the error without the dot, still. The problem I'm trying to figure out is how I could parse the variable as a key.

Comment: Yeah I'm getting the same error even after the removing the dot. The reason I used the dot in the first place is because I needed to use the brackets for something else.

Comment: The brackets help me not to write **site.categories.page.categories | first**, instead the brackets helps to clarify that the *.page.categories | first* is a page variable and not a key on the site.categories collection.

Comment: So I write **site.categories.[page.categories |first]**. It also works without the dot before the brackets but the warning error persists.